# Exponential random variable

Tags: probability

If X is an exponential random variable with parameter 1,how could it be explained that  {1/2}*X  is an exponential random variabile with parameter 2?

Comment: Just find the CDF of $\frac12X$ to get wiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because exponential distributions are closed under scaling: if $X\sim \mathcal E(\lambda)$, then
$$P(X\le x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x<0\\
1 - e^{-\lambda x} & x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
So for any $c>0$, we have that 
$$P(cX\le y)=P(X\le y/c)=\begin{cases}0 & y<0\\
1-e^{-(\lambda/c)\cdot y}& y\ge 0\end{cases}$$
Comparing the two, we know that $cX\sim \mathcal E(\lambda/c)$.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of the exponential r.v. is determined via the expectation.

So you know that $E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. If $\lambda = 1$, then $E[X] = 1$.

Furthermore you'll get by linearity of the expecation:

$$ E\Big[\frac{1}{2} X \Big] = \frac{1}{2}E[X] =\frac{1}{2} $$

Therefore the parameter has to be $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: This is enough if you allready know that $cX$ will have exponential distribution for constant $c>0$.